# All the field values are deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have written a code to make a dynamic table.
    if there is more then 1 row, and when i click on delete button then all the filed value are deleted.
    I need to delete only one-row data for which i press delete button.
    Please look at my code(you need to run this code for understanding my problem)

```js
function addNewRow() {
  // body...
  var table_name = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var index = table_name.rows.length;
  var row = table_name.insertRow(index);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

  /////// 
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var t1 = document.createElement("input");
  t1.type = "text";
  t1.id = 'name';
  cell2.appendChild(t1);
  /////
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var t2 = document.createElement("input");
  t2.type = "email";
  t2.id = 'email';
  cell3.appendChild(t2);
  /////
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var t3 = document.createElement("input");
  var t4 = document.createElement("input");
  t4.type = "button";
  t3.type = "reset";
  t4.id = "Save";
  t3.id = "Delete";
  t4.value = "Save";
  t3.value = "Delete";

  cell4.appendChild(t4);
  cell4.appendChild(t3);

  t4.onclick = function() {
    alert("hello");
  }

  t3.onclick = function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#name').val('');
      $('#email').val('');
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="addNewRow()"> Add a new row</button>
<table border="1" width="500px" height="50px" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th id="id_no">id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`

Comment: _"...then **all** the filed value are deleted"_ - That's not possible - at least not when using an id-selector.

Comment: so sir what should i do for it, because it is dynamically generated when i click on (Add a new row) button

Comment: Since rows are dynamically generated, you can pass some unique id (let's say current timestamp or something else) while calling addNewRow function, and append it to ids of every row, so that every row has unique ids for its fields.

Comment: but sir, let suppose when any one make 10 row and 10 unique id is generated then for every unique id i need to write no of different delete function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add number to make the `ID` unique then you can use this click function

```
t3.onclick = function() {
  var num = this.id.replace('Delete', '');
  $('#name' + num + ', #email' + num).val('') // $('#name0, #email0').val('')
}
```

Demo

```js
var idSuffix = 0;

function addNewRow() {
  // body...
  var table_name = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var index = table_name.rows.length;
  var row = table_name.insertRow(index);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

  /////// 
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var t1 = document.createElement("input");
  t1.type = "text";
  t1.id = 'name'  + idSuffix;
  cell2.appendChild(t1);
  /////
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var t2 = document.createElement("input");
  t2.type = "email";
  t2.id = 'email'  + idSuffix;
  cell3.appendChild(t2);
  /////
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var t3 = document.createElement("input");
  var t4 = document.createElement("input");
  t4.type = "button";
  t3.type = "reset";
  t4.id = "Save" + idSuffix;
  t3.id = "Delete" + idSuffix;
  t4.value = "Save";
  t3.value = "Delete";

  cell4.appendChild(t4);
  cell4.appendChild(t3);

  t4.onclick = function() {
    alert("hello");
  }

  t3.onclick = function() {
    var num = this.id.replace('Delete', '');
    $('#name' + num + ', #email' + num).val('')
  }
  idSuffix++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="addNewRow()"> Add a new row</button>
<table border="1" width="500px" height="50px" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th id="id_no">id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a unique value to the textboxes & buttons.

Here's the code I have added the counter to:

```js
var counter = 0;
function addNewRow() {
  // body...
  var table_name = document.getElementById('mytable');
  var index = table_name.rows.length;
  var row = table_name.insertRow(index);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var t0 = document.createElement("label");
  t0.type = "label";
  t0.innerHTML  =counter;
  cell1.appendChild(t0);

  /////// 
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var t1 = document.createElement("input");
  t1.type = "text";
  t1.id = 'name_'  + counter;
  cell2.appendChild(t1);
  /////
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var t2 = document.createElement("input");
  t2.type = "email";
  t2.id = 'email_'  + counter;
  cell3.appendChild(t2);
  /////
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var t3 = document.createElement("input");
  var t4 = document.createElement("input");
  t4.type = "button";
  t3.type = "reset";
  t4.id = "Save_" + counter;
  t3.id = "Delete_" + counter;
  t4.value = "Save";
  t3.value = "Delete";

  cell4.appendChild(t4);
  cell4.appendChild(t3);

  counter++;
  
  t4.onclick = function() {
    alert("hello");
  }

  t3.onclick = function() {
    var delId = this.id.replace('Delete_', '');
    $('#name_' + delId ).val('');
 $('#email_' + delId ).val('');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="addNewRow()"> Add a new row</button>
<table border="1" width="500px" height="50px" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <th id="id_no">id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```